# Processing e-mail in Odoo 11 without previous threads – is this possible?

Tags: email, odoo, odoo-11

This Odoo company we're working with basically sends a lot of e-mail. One e-mail thread can turn into 100+ e-mails with different people brought into the conversation (CC'd) at different times. Due to the complexity of their e-mail management, they want to use their Gmail interface (Google Hosted) and CC an e-mail into odoo and they want it to get tracked in a thread. I've basically already done that... they have an e-mail like odoo+res.partner-432@domain.com (although it's hashed to not be easily readable) - they CC this and the full body thread gets included in chatter (mail.message) under respective model / id.

The challenge with this: the chatter messages can get huge very fast, due to their e-mail messages (because each e-mail includes main reply, and all previous history on thread). I've looked into some systems that have a "reply above this line" - and it just takes the latest message. And in those systems, eg. ticketing systems such as Zendesk, help scout, I believe the teams are using the ticketing system (not a gmail) and thus there is much more control over the inbox and incoming email (not to mention, those e-mails are usually 1-to-1, not including groups).

My questions:

1. Is there any other workaround that you see here to have odoo pull in only the last e-mail reply and not the full e-mail thread? I could probably build something like this: https://github.com/zapier/email-reply-parser - and hook it into odoos e-mail parsing, but that works on text format e-mails only (not HTML)... only. So it's not bulletproof, and I'm not sure it's worth it.
2. Even if this client DID use odoo 100%, I still don't think it would be possible to get it to work the way they want without major customizations (eg. Odoo's default behavior is to include all past e-mail threads)

I'm curious if anyone here see's any other solutions, otherwise – I doubt there is something here I haven't seen. :) (But very open to be proven incorrect!)

Comment: There is a little mistake in your second alternative: Odoo is not including all past messages. I don't believe there is a chance to parse out "old messages" because every mail client is adding old messages another way :-/ and customizing Odoo could be a very big project.

Comment: Thank you CZoellner, good point - past e-mails are included on client side. I didn't think there was a solution here but wanted to double check. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe someone has a solution, but i bet the chance is very very low.